# MySQL Error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to insert a sample blog post into my 'posts' table in MySQL (using PHP) however I receive a syntax error whenever a large character post is submitted. If I submit content of say 20 characters it works but something like 500 characters will throw the following error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''uid', 'username', 'p_date', 'title', 'content') VALUES('1','Mark Twain', '2014-' at line 1

The 'content' is to be inserted into the database via a varchar(1000) variable. The table is defined in mysql as:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
    pid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid int NOT NULL,
    username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    p_date date NOT NULL,
    title varchar(225) NOT NULL,
    content varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(pid),
    FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
);
```

The actual content I am trying to submit is this:

> Secondly, these missionaries would gradually, and without creating suspicion or exciting alarm, introduce a rudimentary cleanliness among the nobility, and from them it would work down to the people, if the priests could be kept quiet. This would undermine the Church. I mean would be a step toward that. Next, education -- next, freedom -- and then she would begin to crumble. It being my conviction that any Established Church is an established crime, an established slave-pen, I had no scruples, but was willing to assail it in any way or with any weapon that promised to hurt it. Why, in my own former day -- in remote centuries not yet stirring in the womb of time -- there were old Englishmen who imagined that they had been born in a free country: a "free" country with the Corporation Act and the Test still in force in it -- timbers propped against men's liberties and dishonored consciences to shore up an Established Anachronism with.

The insert statement for this is the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts ('uid', 'username', 'p_date', 'title', 'content') VALUES('$uid','$uname', '$date', '$title', '$content')";

if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
    echo "Oops! Something went wrong during the posting process. Please try again. ";
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
    header('Refresh: 1; URL=postingform.php');      
}else{
    // Now return the user to their post page 
    header('Refresh: 0; URL=postlist.php?uid='.$uid.'');
}
```

For some reason it is error-ing out during the INSERT process. The one thing strange I notice is that the date is cut off in the error. To call the date I am using. $date = date("Y-m-d");

I have used this same syntax before without issues.

****Edit

A few posters have pointed out that there are single quotations in my INSERT column statements. I have changed these to back tics and completely removed them but the error still results.

New Error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Court', 'Secondly, these missionaries would gradually, and without creating su' at line 1

There is something still wrong with my insert syntax but everything I am reading says it should be correct.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (`uid`, `username`, `p_date`, `title`, `content`) VALUES('$uid','$uname', '$p_date', '$title', '$content')";
```

Comment: You are using single quotes where you should be using back ticks or no escape errors at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove all the quotes in (for your columns)

```
('uid', 'username', 'p_date', 'title', 'content')
```

Those aren't the correct column identifiers

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

use

```
(uid, username, p_date, title, content)
```

or use backticks.

```
(`uid`, `username`, `p_date`, `title`, `content`)
```

*However* and as a quick FYI, backticks are mostly used for reserved keywords, or if a table/column contains spaces, hyphens.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

---

The error message was letting you know here

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''uid',
>   ^--« right there

Notice the quote just before `'uid'`? That's where the problem starts.

---

**Edit:**

Try the following using prepared statements and replace `xxx` with your own credentials.

This should take care of the quotes issue from your input values.

You will need to add the variables according to your inputs.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

$uid = ""; // replace with proper value
$uname = ""; // replace with proper value
$date = ""; // replace with proper value
$title = ""; // replace with proper value
$content = ""; // replace with proper value

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (`uid`, `username`, `p_date`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $uid, $uname, $date, $title, $content);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

        else{
          echo "Success";
        }

$stmt->close(); // Statement
$conn->close(); // MySQLi
```

---

***Footnotes:***

In order to allow single and/or double quotes, based yourself on the following, while using the [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function.

```
$content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
```

This will enter in DB properly:
`Bob's sister was here today and said: "Bob, what lovely hair you have!".`

Comment: Still no luck. I have removing quotes and backtics and the error that results when entering the information is:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Court', 'Secondly, these missionaries would gradually, and without creating su' at line 1

Comment: @user3055632 Try using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the values. I.e.: `mysql_real_escape_string($content)` or `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content'])` etc. depending on the form's element name. Or this sometimes helps `('".$uid."','$uname."', '".$date."', '".$title."', '".$content."')` you may need to adjust for `$uid`

Comment: @user3055632 I suggest you switch over to either `mysqli_` or PDO. It will facilitate the task of dealing with quotes in your values. See the following links [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: @user3055632 I've put together a prepared statements method for you. Look under my **Edit:** that should take care of the issues with the quotes from input values.

Comment: @user3055632 I also added something else; see **Footnotes** and go over my entire answer carefully. Entering `Bob's sister was here today and said: "Bob, what lovely hair you have!".` into a POST form method, was successful and showed up exactly like that when tested.

Comment: Thank you for the well written response. Looks like it was the quotations marks that were causing this error. I thought I had covered this by sanitizing my data beforehand using

  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

To fix the problem while still using good old mysql_ syntax I just had to run my data through the mysql_real_escape_string(); function. This isn't the best way to do it but it will work for now. Cheers!

Comment: @user3055632 You're very much welcome and glad to hear that it's been resolved, *cheers!*